# Dependency Injection: Dagger removing sub-graph

Tags: android, dagger

When you want to add a sub-objectgraph to your global object graph you use:

```
newObjectGraph = objectgraph.plus(new SubModule("SomeConfig"));
```

Now you are done with SubModule and you want to let it go (or perhaps you want to replace it with SubModule("AnotherConfig"). How would you do that? In fact do I need to do anything? Or I can simply do:

```
anotherNewObjectGraph = objectgraph.plus(new SubModule("AnotherConfig"));
```

PS: this question is based on a presentation about Dagger.1 on Android by Jake Wharton.

- http://jakewharton.com/presentation/2013-11-14-devoxx/
- Specific slide that talks about this adding and removing procedure:
  https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/android-apps-with-dagger-devoxx-2013?slide=113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I got you right, but I'll try to shed some light here. Dagger's `plus` method creates a new graph and leaves the old one intact. From the docs:

```
Returns a new object graph that includes all of the objects in this graph...
```

This means that as long as you keep the instance of your "root" object graph (`objectGraph` in your example) you'll always be able to create your scoped graphs (or sub-graphs if you prefer the naming).

So in your example both `newObjectGraph` and `anotherNewObjectGraph` are completly different graphs that only share what's in `objectGraph`.

Here's a link to the github [file](https://github.com/square/dagger/blob/master/core/src/main/java/dagger/ObjectGraph.java) for the ObjectGraph.

As long as you don't keep references to the scoped graphs the GC will take care of cleaning them for you.